# PDFBox - how to change font or encoding in existing PDF document

Tags: java, pdfbox

Is it possible to change the font or encoding in the existing PDF document programatically?
There is many advices on the Web how to do it when a new document is created,
but I cannot find any example showing existing document transformation.
Please help.

Comment: Changing the encoding of a font object is complicated, at least if you need to change all strings using that font to match the new encoding. Essentially you have to find all usages of the font as is and change them accordingly. Furthermore, changing the encoding itself can be difficult, too. E.g. changing a simple font with *WinAnsiEncoding* to some multi-byte encoding means you have to make the simple font a composite font which in some cases is really non-trivial, you may even need a completely new font program to embed. Subset embedded fonts impose additional problems.

Comment: I like complicated task, but I don't have a knowledge. I don't want to change font to utf, but only single byte Arial to single byte polish ArialCE.

Comment: I've already built loops enumerating all document pages and all objects in pages, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: *"single byte Arial to single byte polish Arial"* - ah, so you want to change both font and encoding. You say single byte encoding. That's possible for simple and for composite fonts. Which is it in your case? And is the font embedded? If it is, is it embedded fully or as subset? And do you have a copy of the replacement font you are allowed to embed? And which encodings do you have and want exactly?

Comment: [my pdf and font](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_7KtXNLQiYJ7uVcpm1HNnw9klriwlVav/view?usp=sharing) here is my pdf and font Arial CE. Could you look at it? I don't know if the font is embeded and composited, But I'd like to have entire font in the PDF.

Comment: I get *access denied* on that link.

Comment: @mkl, I didn't noticed your last comment. I searched the web an finally I prepared a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  the solution:

Look at the first reply and write the code.

Comment: This answer looks strangely familiar. It will work only for very simple PDFs. (See the very first comment by mkl)

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, you are rigth, so I changed may my solution description adequately.

Comment: That's even less helpful now. The best thing would be to keep the original answer, mention the first comment, and link to wherever you got your code or the inspiration for it. If it is from another SO answer (I think it is, but can't find it, so I may be wrong), then decide whether your question is duplicate.